# Forking and Pipe processes with loop in C

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe, fork

I'm studying about Forking and Piping, and I clearly understand how to connect parent and multiple children.

Now I'm having trouble with loop that Circle.

Here's the example

Parent -- Child 1 -- Child 2 -- Child 3 -- Child 4

'- -  - -- - - - - - - - - - - --- -----    - - - - - - - - - - - -  '

I built this one round of calculation, and I want to make another calculation with same processes.

I hope that this round never ends without some condition (if x == 10)

After I got result, I sent another data to Child 1 using existed pipe, but Child 1 never answers.

How can I make a loop with this condition?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define PROCESS_NUM 5

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int pids[PROCESS_NUM];
    int pipes[PROCESS_NUM + 1][2];
    int i;
    int pid;
    int end=1;
    for (i = 0; i < PROCESS_NUM + 1; i++) {
        if (pipe(pipes[i]) == -1) {
            printf("Error with creating pipe\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < PROCESS_NUM; i++) {
        pids[i] = fork();
        if (pids[i] == -1) {
            printf("Error with creating process\n");
            return 2;
        }
        if (pids[i] == 0) {
            // Child process
            pid = getpid();
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < PROCESS_NUM + 1; j++) {
                if (i != j) {
                    close(pipes[j][0]);
                }
                if (i + 1 != j) {
                    close(pipes[j][1]);
                }
            }
            int x;
            if (read(pipes[i][0], &x, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
                printf("Error at reading\n");
                return 3;
            }
            printf("(%d) Got %d\n", pid, x);
            if(x==3){
                printf("Done!");
                if (write(pipes[i + 1][1], &x, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
                    printf("Error at writing\n");
                    return 4;
                }
                printf("(%d) Sent %d\n", pid, x);
            }else{
            x++;
            if (write(pipes[i + 1][1], &x, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
                printf("Error at writing\n");
                return 4;
            }
            printf("(%d) Sent %d\n", pid, x);
            }
            
            
            //close(pipes[i][0]);
            //close(pipes[i + 1][1]);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // Main process
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < PROCESS_NUM + 1; j++) {
        if (j != PROCESS_NUM) {
            close(pipes[j][0]);
        }
        if (j != 0) {
            close(pipes[j][1]);
        }
    }
    int y = 0;
    printf("Main process sent %d\n", y);
    if (write(pipes[0][1], &y, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
        printf("Error at writing\n");
        return 4;
    }
    if (read(pipes[PROCESS_NUM][0], &y, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
        printf("Error at reading\n");
        return 3;
    }
    printf("The final result is %d\n", y);
    
    if (write(pipes[0][1], &y, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
        printf("Error at writing\n");
        return 4;
    }
    close(pipes[0][1]);
    close(pipes[PROCESS_NUM][0]);

    for (i = 0; i < PROCESS_NUM; i++) {
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make another calculation with same processes.

> I sent another data to Child 1 using existed pipe, but Child 1 never answers.

That's understandable, since each child does `return 0;` after one run - you have not programmed it (in a loop) to read/write more than once.

> I hope that this round never ends without some condition (if x == 10)

A program doesn't behave according to your hopes, but according to how you wrote it.

> How can I make a loop with this condition?

Since you never increment x above 3, this condition would never be met.

Comment: In the code, I wrote x==3 for test, to know that this program works fine. When I disable return 0 in the code of child, Main process tries to send y=0. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You must not _disable return 0_ - you must make a loop around the lines between `int x;` and `return 0;`.